# What is the serial number?

Tags: avr, atmel, jtag

I am trying to connect a JTAG ICE Mk II Emulator from ATMEL to my USB drive. and do some development on a 32 bit ATMEL STK 1000 board.

I am using AVR32 Studio and I can't seem to get it fully configured. While the JTAG is recognised by Windows, I don't know how to configure the "serial number" under the connection tab in AVR32.

Please help...I haven't found much documentation either on this.

Comment: Wonder who flagged this as being off topic... The tools mentioned are programming tools so asking about how to properly configure them is just fine, I'd say. +1

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. I am using AVRStudio 5 (not AVR32 Studio afaik), and it automatically detects my JTAG ICE MK II. Im working on the UC3A0512 chip aswell, although it's a homebrewn board. Can you provide more details?

Comment: AVR Studio 5 is much more advanced and yes, that one automatically recognises my JTAG as well. However, the STK1000 is only supported by AVR32 Studio (2.6). I'm trying to "force" the Studio into recognising the emulator by adding a new target and configuring it manually. One of the required fields is "Serial Number" under the "Connection" tab. That's all the info I've got and I can't find much more anywhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it helps. But i really didn't like AVR studio 4 and couldn't be bothered when 5 came out, so i switched to Eclipse with the AVR plugin and AVR dude and never looked back. 
It you are struggling with some ancient AVR Studio, i would try this. 
At least its meets all my simple requirements. Not sure what yours are.

Comment: I also do Android development with Eclipse and that plugin, hopefully they won't "fight each other". Yes, I'll give that a try. I hope it's not asking too much, but can you please link me to these resources and...what's "AVR dude"? I'm a complete noob when it comes to these, I'm happy just to get the thing working right now.

Comment: Hi mate. Sorry i never got back to you on this. I do both Android and AVR work on Eclipse also. They don't conflict with each other. Not even in the same workspace. I'm pretty sure this is the eclipse plugin: http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/The_AVR_Eclipse_Plugin but i having done development in it in a while now. If you are a total noob, it's a steep learning curve. AVRfreaks is a good website for help on this stuff.

Comment: Just a quick elaboration on AVRdude: AVRdude is the program that will interface to your programmer. GCC is your compilier (or win-GCC on windows), or some other C compiler, i think the plugin will guide you through these steps anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input... I've overcome the problem since then. Apparently it was a faulty JTag Emulator... Gave me quite a few headaches though.